# Issue reading in line of file with Qt and vectors

Tags: c++, qt, vector, qtableview

I have an issue in Qt where I am running code to generate a vector of class objects and output them to a TableView. Whenever I run the code it only reads the first line of the file. I put the same code and change the TableView part into a standard cout and everything works fine.

```
showReservations::showReservations(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::showReservations)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

std::vector<reservation> currReservations;

//Initalize the vector set
//Runs the ReadFlightSchedule with the vector set and returns a 1 if there is a
//failure and 0 if all is good
if (ReadReservations(currReservations) == 1)
{
    //This sets a label to red showing the user an error reading the file
    ui->label->setText("<font color = 'red'>Error Reading File! Oops</font>");
}
else {
    //hides the error label since the file read good.
    ui->label->hide();

    //Generates the column header names
    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(currReservations.size(), 5, this);
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(QString("Flier Name")));
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem(QString("Flight Date")));
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, new QStandardItem(QString("Flight Number")));
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, new QStandardItem(QString("Seat Designation")));
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, new QStandardItem(QString("Reservation ID")));

    //Sets the values from the vector sets to the appropriate column and row sets.
    for (int i = 0; i < currReservations.size(); i++)
    {
        model->setItem(i, 0, new QStandardItem(QString::fromStdString(currReservations[i].getName())));
        model->setItem(i, 1, new QStandardItem(QString::fromStdString(currReservations[i].getDate())));
        model->setItem(i, 2, new QStandardItem(QString::fromStdString(currReservations[i].getFlightNum())));
        model->setItem(i, 3, new QStandardItem(QString::fromStdString(currReservations[i].getSeatDesg())));
        model->setItem(i, 4, new QStandardItem(QString::fromStdString(currReservations[i].getReservationID())));
    }

    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    ui->tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
   }
}

showReservations::~showReservations()
{
delete ui;
}

//User Generated Functions
int showReservations::ReadReservations(std::vector<reservation>& Res)
{
std::ifstream flightFile;
std::string fName, lName, date, seatDes, flightNum;
int error = 0;

flightFile.open("reservations.txt");

if(!flightFile)
{
    //returns a error value if there is a problem reading the file
    error = 1;
    return error;
}
else
{
    //Start reading files and sticks them into a class object and sticks the object into the vector set        
    while (flightFile >> fName >> lName >> date >> flightNum >> seatDes)
    {
        reservation newRes(fName, lName, date, flightNum, seatDes);
        Res.push_back(newRes);
    }
}

flightFile.close();
return error;

}
```

Contents of the file:
Jane Doe 04202013 602 1A
Nick Deal 05012013 604 2B
John Smith 05012013 604 2A

Working non-Qt code:

```
int ReadReservations(std::vector<reservation>& Res);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
std::ifstream flightFile;
std::string name, date, seatDes, flightNum, line;

std::vector<reservation> Res;

flightFile.open("reservations.txt");
ReadReservations(Res);

for (int i = 0; i < Res.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << Res[i].getName() << std::endl << Res[i].getDate() << std::endl << Res[i].getFlightNum() << std::endl << Res[i].getSeatDesg() << std::endl;
}
return 0;


}

int ReadReservations(std::vector<reservation>& Res)
{
 std::ifstream flightFile;
std::string fName, lName, date, seatDes, flightNum;
int error = 0;

flightFile.open("reservations.txt");

if(!flightFile)
{
    //returns a error value if there is a problem reading the file
    error = 1;
    return error;
}
else
{
    //Start reading files and sticks them into a class object and sticks the object into the vector set        
    while (flightFile >> fName >> lName >> date >> flightNum >> seatDes)
    {
        //flightFile >> fName >> lName >> date >> flightNum >> seatDes;
        reservation newRes(fName, lName, date, flightNum, seatDes);
        Res.push_back(newRes);
    }
}

flightFile.close();
return error;

}
```

I have something similar working on a different file. I just cannot figure out what the issue is with this one. This is for homework.

Thanks for all the help

Comment: try ``model->appendRow()`` : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#appendRow

Comment: The problem is that I have something almost exactly the same in a different form that works correctly. I looked at appendRow() and if I can't figure out what is going on with my current code I can go down that route or attempt to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `appendRow` like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < currReservations.size(); i++)
{
    QList<QStandardItem*> row;
    row << new QStandardItem(QString::fromStdString(currReservations[i].getName())));
    row << new QStandardItem(QString::fromStdString(currReservations[i].getDate())));
    row << new QStandardItem(QString::fromStdString(currReservations[i].getFlightNum())));
    row << new QStandardItem(QString::fromStdString(currReservations[i].getSeatDesg())));
    row << new QStandardItem(QString::fromStdString(currReservations[i].getReservationID())));

    model->appendRow(row);
}
```